# Sending POST data in steps using react axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I want to add code verification to my react app. Users will fill a form and receive a random 4 digit code on their phone for verification.

Here's the code in NodeJS to create a random 4 digit code and send it to the user's phone.

```
module.exports = (app) => {
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {

    const from = 'Test Message'
    const to = req.body.number
    const text = req.body.message
    const code = (Math.floor(1000+Math.random()*9000))

    // nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text)

    res.status(200).send('success')
})
}
```

I used a post request using axios in react to send this data to the server.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(sms)
    axios.post('/send', sms)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I don't understand where to go from here. Is there a way an **async** function can be used so the post request can still send the verification code back to the server and verify it?

Comment: Have flagged as `Needs improvement` - it's not clear what you're asking here, if you want us to tell you what to do with your app, how to make requests, etc. The question needs to be more specific, or at the very least, more detailed. There's a number of questions here, each with their own possible responses.

At the very least, to answer the last one, you will need to make a new POST request from the UI once the user has received their code and entered it into an `<input>` field.

Comment: Usually this is trigger by the SDK service, which will send a request to some endpoint you provide after success verified.